# Mod_rewrite not working properly anymore

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been using

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.+)\.js$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.+)\.css$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.+)\.jpe?g$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.+)\.png$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.+)\.gif$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.+)\.html?$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.+)\.swf$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
ReWriteRule .* - [L]
```

but after moving to a new server, the rewriting has stopped working and I just see a directory index the root of the site

i do have

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index\.php?page=$1    [QSA,NC,L]
```

later in the file.

Seems like something may have changed config wise for Apache but I don't have any idea what.

Comment: Make sure `RewriteEngine On` is at the top of the script. And since it's a new server, you need to make sure `AllowOverride All` is in the apache config. Have you checked those?

Comment: I have checked those and they are there.